# How to avoid alarm trigger at time of set?

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I am setting alarm with an interval of 2 hours. It work very perfect but the problem is, at the time of set it trigger the alarm.
It don't have to trigger alarm at time of set rest is all ok.

```
        Intent _myIntent = new Intent(activity, MyReceiverStartPush.class);
        _myIntent.putExtra("msg", "Feed");

        PendingIntent _myPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                activity, 0, _myIntent, 0);
        AlarmManager _myAlarmManager = (AlarmManager) activity
                .getSystemService(Service.ALARM_SERVICE);

        _myAlarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                System.currentTimeMillis(), (AlarmManager.INTERVAL_HOUR)
                        * 2, _myPendingIntent);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `System.currentTimeMillis()` (which is the reason) you should use `System.currentTimeMillis() + 2H` there